# Заполнение массива уникальными значениями (не числа)

Tags: javascript, массивы, классы, typescript

Задача: заполнить массив уникальными объектами(классами). Проблема была в том, что объекты это не числа, и сравнивать их не так просто, как числа (мне, как новичку). В итоге, в каждый класс добавил уникальный идентификатор по которому и сравнивал.
Интересно, можно ли было сделать это по другому?

```js
        let arr20: Item[] = [];
        let uniq: boolean;
        let tmpItem: Item;
        while (arr20.length < itemsNum) { 
            uniq = true;
            tmpItem = generator.getRandomItem();
            for (var i = 0; i < arr20.length; i++) {
                if (arr20[i].gItemType == tmpItem.gItemType) {
                    uniq = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (uniq == true) {
                arr20.push(tmpItem);
            }
        }
```

Comment: А что значит - *заполнить массив уникальными объектами*? Как определяется уникальность? Например, `var a = {}, a1= {}` в `a` и `a1` хранятся уникальные объекты.

Comment: В данном случае, в каждом виде объекта (тут идет речь об одежде) есть уникальный ItemType, у каждого свой. Я сравниваю их.

Comment: Эффективность вашего кода зависит от значений, которые находятся в `ItemType`. Если, допустим, это какой-нибудь `guid`, тогда хорошо. Если это числа от `1` до `itemsNum`, то  ужасно.

Comment: в данном случае, это просто числа (0-20), так как классов всего 20. Я только учусь, поэтому задача относительно простая)

Comment: В таком случае вы выбрали не лучший вариант. Производительность может быть ужасная, и она не будет детерминирована. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, приведите код функции `getRandomItem`.